# How to get additional social icons in prestashop block social module

Tags: module, prestashop-1.5

In my prestashop site i have implemented block social module and by default i can able to get facebook,twitter and rss social icons.How can i get addtional social icons such as google,pinterest and you tube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit the blocksocial.php

this code i have added the google link

find a "getContent" method on your blocksocial.php in your module folder

and change it to

```
public function getContent()
{
    // If we try to update the settings
    $output = '';
    if (isset($_POST['submitModule']))
    {   
        Configuration::updateValue('blocksocial_facebook', (($_POST['facebook_url'] != '') ? $_POST['facebook_url']: ''));
        Configuration::updateValue('blocksocial_twitter', (($_POST['twitter_url'] != '') ? $_POST['twitter_url']: ''));     
        Configuration::updateValue('blocksocial_rss', (($_POST['rss_url'] != '') ? $_POST['rss_url']: ''));
        Configuration::updateValue('blocksocial_google', (($_POST['google_url'] != '') ? $_POST['google_url']: ''));                
        $this->_clearCache('blocksocial.tpl');
        $output = '<div class="conf confirm">'.$this->l('Configuration updated').'</div>';
    }

    return '
    <h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>
    '.$output.'
    <form action="'.Tools::htmlentitiesutf8($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'" method="post">
        <fieldset class="width2">               
            <label for="facebook_url">'.$this->l('Facebook URL: ').'</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook_url" name="facebook_url" value="'.Tools::safeOutput((Configuration::get('blocksocial_facebook') != "") ? Configuration::get('blocksocial_facebook') : "").'" />
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>     
            <label for="twitter_url">'.$this->l('Twitter URL: ').'</label>
            <input type="text" id="twitter_url" name="twitter_url" value="'.Tools::safeOutput((Configuration::get('blocksocial_twitter') != "") ? Configuration::get('blocksocial_twitter') : "").'" />
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>     
            <label for="rss_url">'.$this->l('RSS URL: ').'</label>
            <input type="text" id="rss_url" name="rss_url" value="'.Tools::safeOutput((Configuration::get('blocksocial_rss') != "") ? Configuration::get('blocksocial_rss') : "").'" />
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 
            <label for="rss_url">'.$this->l('Goolge Plug: ').'</label>
            <input type="text" id="google_url" name="google_url" value="'.Tools::safeOutput((Configuration::get('blocksocial_google') != "") ? Configuration::get('blocksocial_google') : "").'" />

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>                     
            <br /><center><input type="submit" name="submitModule" value="'.$this->l('Update settings').'" class="button" /></center>
        </fieldset>
    </form>';
}
```

and after that find "hookDisplayFooter" method

and change it to

```
public function hookDisplayFooter()
{
    if (!$this->isCached('blocksocial.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'facebook_url' => Configuration::get('blocksocial_facebook'),
            'twitter_url' => Configuration::get('blocksocial_twitter'),
            'rss_url' => Configuration::get('blocksocial_rss'),
            'google_url' => Configuration::get('blocksocial_google')
        ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocksocial.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
}
```

last you need to change the template file.
if your template file override by your theme means find a "module" folder from the theme foler and find "blocksocial" folder and edit the blocksocial.tpl

if it is not override by your theme file means you can edit the blocksocial.tpl in you module folder

the changes should be

```
<div id="social_block">
    <p class="title_block">{l s='Follow us' mod='blocksocial'}</p>
    <ul>
        {if $facebook_url != ''}<li class="facebook"><a href="{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{l s='Facebook' mod='blocksocial'}</a></li>{/if}
        {if $twitter_url != ''}<li class="twitter"><a href="{$twitter_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{l s='Twitter' mod='blocksocial'}</a></li>{/if}
        {if $rss_url != ''}<li class="rss"><a href="{$rss_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{l s='RSS' mod='blocksocial'}</a></li>{/if}
        {if $google_url != ''}<li class="google"><a href="{$google_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{l s='Google' mod='blocksocial'}</a></li>{/if}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: After update the code i can able to get google link alone in my front end.Facebook,twitter and rss are not displaying.

Comment: have you seen the confutation from the backend? can you see all links there?

Comment: Yes in backend i can see all the links.i have configure the module and tried by reset once again too but still there is no change in front end and in source code too only one li for google alone getting generated.

Comment: in "hookDisplayFooter" method print all the values and check what response you get? try this print_r(Configuration::get('blocksocial_facebook'));

Comment: There is no change.still i am getting the google text link alone.

Comment: what response you when you print the values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42585/discussion-between-shaik-rilwan-and-rama-priya)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the social login module to add social icons for sharing as well as for login  process from link below:

http://loginradius-social-plugins.s3.amazonaws.com/Prestashop/v1.5/sociallogin.zip

It is working good at my website.

Answer (score 0):

This looks incomplete to me. Do you not have to also change 'sprite_pict_social_block.png' to get the additional logos?

Comment: yes we have to change the sprite_pict_social_block.png and have to update the css